# About interrupt 21 h

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, calling-convention

I am new to Assembly Language programming.

I wanted to know that is it true that interrupts should be moved to Ah register?

Is it wrong to move any interrupts to AL registers?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. The DOS int 21h dispatcher expects a major function number in `ah`, you must use that otherwise it will not work. See the documentation for details. PS: avoid DOS unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: DOS int 21h and the others and the bios ones and any other "operating system" that uses that design is going to have a defined interface, now that doesnt mean publicly published, but the dos/bios ones are look for ralf brown interrupt list.  FOR EACH system call there is one or more registers that are used as inputs for that call, you have to look up each call, prepare the registers required on the way and get your results as defined on the way out if there are results.

Comment: DOS is still very much alive and well, just a very small set of communities that use it.  And assume each operating system has its own system call solution, so for example dont assume that windows, linux, etc on an x86 make dos calls, assume that they dont and also assume that they dont synthesize dos calls

Answer (score 2):

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_API, and other documentation: http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html

(Also Ralf Brown's interrupt list has details about many other `int` numbers: http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm.  The standard convention is still a "function code" in `AH` that selects which system call you want out of that group over services.)

The DOS "kernel" code in the interrupt handler is going to read `AH` to find out what function you want.  Then reads whatever other registers, depending on which code runs.

You can think of `int 21h` as a fancy `call` into the DOS kernel, to a dispatcher that uses `AH` to index a table of function pointers to dispatch to the real function.  Then that function uses args in other registers.

A few of those do take an arg in `AL`, but many take an arg in `DL` (like a character to print). Some of them don't read `AL` on input, but most write it as an output.

For functions where `AL` is not an input, you can have whatever you want in `AL` when `int 21h` runs.  So sure, you could have another copy of the call number in `AL` as well as `AH`; it will do no harm.  But you *must* have the right values in the documented registers.

---

System call mechanisms for most other OSes are similar: put args in registers then invoke a trap instruction.  e.g. Linux puts call number in `EAX`, and uses `int 0x80` (32-bit) or `syscall` (64-bit).  Only a few (like 32-bit FreeBSD / MacOS) pass system call args on the stack.

OSes other than DOS do not support `int 21h`.  e.g. a 32-bit Windows executable will just crash (itself, not the whole machine) if it executes an `int 21h`.